# Mule 4 Munits : Call flow with basic Authenication

Tags: mule, basic-authentication

I am using Mule 4, I am trying to create a test case where I want to call flow have Http listener with basic authentication using flow-ref

```
<http:authentication>
    <http:basic-authentication username="${admin.user}" password="${admin.password}" />
</http:authentication>
```

But I am getting basic authentication error, Below approach of Mule 3 is not working

```
<munit:inbound-properties>
    <munit:inbound-property key="Authorization" value="Basic YWRtaW46OWJjRFAyclF3RXBlamRYelpW==" />
     <munit:inbound-property key="username" value="admin" />
     <munit:inbound-property key="password" value="123" />
</munit:inbound-properties>
```

Is there any way to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

In Mule 4, support for HTTP basic authentication has been devolved somewhat to Spring Security. The below Mulesoft tutorial details the Mule 4 approach.

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Tutorial-how-to-create-a-simple-Mule-4-http-basic-authentication-application